# Bootstrap 3 checkbox right side of text / button on own row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the [current setup](http://www.bootply.com/QwIQWpJD5r).

```
<div class="container" data-ng-controller="publicHome">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" style="background: black;">
        <form data-ng-submit="signIn()" class="form-horizontal">


            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" data-ng-model="email" placeholder="email" class="form-control">
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" data-ng-model="password" placeholder="password" class="form-control">
            </div>


            <label class="checkbox pull-right">
                remember me
                <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="rememberMe">
            </label>


            <div class="form-group center-block">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success center-block">sign in</button>
            </div>


        </form>
        <div data-ng-bind="message" class="text-center">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to:

- Get the check box on the right side of the remember me text AND have both of the right side of the form
- Have the button on it's own row underneath the remember me

As you can see I'm nearly there!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
<div class="form-group mycheckboxdiv">
    <label>
        remember me
        <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="rememberMe" class="pull-right mycheckbox">
    </label>
</div>
```

and for your own css:

```
.mycheckbox{
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-left:5px;
}
.mycheckboxdiv{
   text-align:right;
}
```

See this:
http://www.bootply.com/a6Jl6EDD8R

Comment: Oh I must of been slightly unclear, I also want the remember me and checkbox on the right side of the form!

Comment: Updated question (my fault)

Comment: Yes. Finally you solved my problem I used it like this and got nice big fat checkboxes(as big as the inputs).
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <label for="chkPrint">
                                <span style="color:white;">Print</span>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="chkPrint" class="form-control" />
                            </label>
                        </div>